# passing parameter from gridview

Tags: c#, gridview

trying to pass parameter from a label in gridview, only the label text from the first row are passed.

not sure what is missing.

```
 protected void GV1_OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "edit")
        {


            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    Label lbl_taskID = (Label)row.FindControl("lbl_taskID");

                    Session["TaskID"] = lbl_taskID.Text;

                    Response.Redirect("~/tasks_edit.aspx");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug your code? Which line is gave error? What is your error message? Be spesific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the auto generated EDIT button from gridview wizard and it is working.

sorry for your time waste.

Answer (score 1):

You are breaking loop with `Response.Redirect` You need to put the do `Response.Redirect` out side loop to set all value, you also need to concatenate value of `lbl_taskID` all rows instead of over writting.

```
protected void GV1_OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string taskIds = string.Empty;
    if (e.CommandName == "edit")
    {


        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                Label lbl_taskID = (Label)row.FindControl("lbl_taskID");

                if(Session["TaskID"] != null)
                  taskIds = Session["TaskID"].ToString();
                Session["TaskID"] = taskIds + lbl_taskID.Text + ",";                 
            }
        }
        Response.Redirect("~/tasks_edit.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've put the Response.Redirect outside the loop but still getting the first row text

Comment: Are you using updated code with statement Session["TaskID"] = taskIds + lbl_taskID.Text + ",";

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `foreach` loop, but you are using the loop to  assign a single value to a single `Session` variable. So what do you expect?

However, i would assume that your last row is assigned not the first.

You need to put `Response.Redirect("~/tasks_edit.aspx")` outside of the loop since it will abort the current request. You might want to assign the row which is currently in edit-mode:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gridView1.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
    {
        Label lbl_taskID = (Label)row.FindControl("lbl_taskID");
        Session["TaskID"] = lbl_taskID.Text;
        break;
    }
}
Response.Redirect("~/tasks_edit.aspx");
```

Side-note: you don't need to check the `DataControlRowType` since [`GridView.Rows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rows.aspx) only returns rows with `DataControlRowType.DataRow` anyway(unlike `RowDataBound`-event).

**Edit**: Instead of `RowCommand` i would use the click event of the `LinkButton`:

```
protected void EditLink_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get the LinkButton reference
    LinkButton link = (LinkButton)  sender;
    // get the GridViewRow reference via NamingContainer
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow) link.NamingContainer;
    Label lbl_taskID = (Label) row.FindControl("lbl_taskID");
    Session["TaskID"] = lbl_taskID.Text;
    Response.Redirect("~/tasks_edit.aspx");
}
```

Comment: lets start from beginning: a gridview each row has link button for editing the record, using a label text which have the record id, trying to pass that id to the editing page tasks_edit.aspx

Comment: So why don't you use the `Hyperlinks`-`Click`-event instead? I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**If only the first row is used, then why you using foreach loop?** You can simply `find the control of the 0th row.`

```
if (e.CommandName == "edit") //this makes sure that you have a row
{
  Label lbl_taskID = (Label)GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("lbl_taskID");
  Session["TaskID"] = lbl_taskID.Text;  
  Response.Redirect("~/tasks_edit.aspx");
}
```

**If you mean label text from currently editing column** then, `take the index of the editing column` from the `CommandArgument` and get the label

```
if (e.CommandName == "edit") //this makes sure that you have a row
{
      int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); //currently editing row index
      Label lbl_taskID = (Label)GridView1.Rows[index].FindControl("lbl_taskID");
      Session["TaskID"] = lbl_taskID.Text;  
      Response.Redirect("~/tasks_edit.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How come you have `lbl_taskID` in every row? In your foreach loop your doing-

```
Label lbl_taskID = (Label)row.FindControl("lbl_taskID");
```

You are actually only taking the value of `lbl_taskID` present in your first row. The next rows will not have the same element again. Your coding is wrong. You will need to name your labels in each row with some thing like this- `label0`, `label1`,...  then in your code you can do-

```
            int i=0;
            foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                 Label xyz = (Label)row.FindControl("Label"+i);
                 Session["TaskID"+i] =xyz.Text; //to have unique session variables
                 i++;
            }
            Response.Redirect("~/tasks_edit.aspx"); // you should redirect only when you come out of the loop
```